# How to make this div container wider?

Tags: css

I know very little css. I'm trying to make the logo wider but I can't do it. I think that's because it's in other div container which is smaller. How can I achieve it? Thank you very much. 
link: http://rotvajler.greatsystemdesign.com/

Comment: Can you post a working code snippet so we can help you with this? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: oh! how can i get code snippet? i dont really have the code, i could only paste a whole header code or whatever

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this CSS to allow the image to reach a width that is in the correct proportion to its height:

```
.logo-block .logo {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

This will overwrite all the other rules in media queries which restrict the width of the image.

Comment: thank you very much! solved it! one more question: how can i make the logo not appear on phone?

Comment: use a media query with `display: none`

Comment: i did but i says that it wont be displayed as im dont have enough rated! thank you